# Unix Network Programming:undefined reference to `Socket'，‘Bind’，‘Listen’，‘Write’?

Tags: c

I'm learning 《UNIX Network Programming .volume1》. However, when I tried to run the example shown in the book, I got an error. I downloaded unpv13e-master from https://www.github.com/unpbook/unpv13e and compiled the code following the instructions:

1. `chmod -R 744 unpv13e-master`
2. `cd unpv13e-master`

   `./configure`

   `cd lib`

   `make`

   `cd ../libfree`

   `make`

   `cp libunp.a /usr/lib`
3. `vim   lib/unp.h`   change `#include "../config.h"` to `#include "config.h"`
4. `cp lib/unp.h /usr/include`

   `cp config.h /usr/include`

and I still get the error. This is the code I'm trying to run on my UBUNTU 20.4 system.

```
#include "unp.h"
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int listenfd,connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t ticks;

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);

    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);

    Bind(listenfd,(SA *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    Listen(listenfd,LISTENQ);

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        connfd = Accept(listenfd,(SA *)NULL,NULL);

        ticks =time(NULL);
        snprintf(buff,sizeof(buff),"%.24s\r\n",ctime(&ticks));
        Write(connfd,buff,strlen(buff));

        Close(connfd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are those functions capitalized?

Comment: The library build process builds a *static library* named `libunp.a`. You need to link with this library in your own programs.

Comment: @StephenNewell The authors of the book have created wrappers around the standard functions.

Comment: @StephenNewell Those are wrap functions defined in unpv13e ,for example ,you can find "Socket" funtion in file unpv13e/lib/wrapsock.c ,all of these files are compiled to libunp.a

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Its working with param "-l unp"

Comment: After `cp libunp.a /usr/lib` then yes that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you are compiling/linking. I had a similar problem and this is how I compiled the code.

The problem is that the library is generated with ranlib and not with ar. This means that linking using -lunp doesn't work.

For those trying to run the programs in the book this is what I did.

1. clone repository from https://github.com/hailinzeng/Unix-Network-Programming

```
git clone https://github.com/unpbook/unpv13e
```

2. enter the unpv13e created directory

```
cd unpv13e
```

3)run configure

```
./configure
```

4. change to lib directory

```
cd lib
```

5)run make inside this dir

```
make
```

note that at the end of the log says "ranlib ../libunp.a". So, is using ranlib not ar.

```
extract from the end of the make log:
a - wraplib.o
a - wrapsock.o
a - wrapstdio.o
a - wrappthread.o
a - wrapunix.o
a - write_fd.o
a - writen.o
a - writable_timeo.o
ranlib ../libunp.a
```

Now the file libunp.a should be create inside the unpv13e folder:

```
$ ls
aclocal.m4     inetd            Makefile     sigio
advio          install-sh       Makefile.in  sock
bcast          intro            mcast        sockopt
config.guess   ioctl            mysdr        sparc64-unknown-freebsd5.1
config.h       ipopts           names        ssntp
config.h.in    key              nonblock     streams
config.log     lib              oob          tcpcliserv
config.status  libfree          ping         test
config.sub     libgai           README       threads
configure      libroute         route        traceroute
configure.in   libunp.a<----         rtt          udpcksum
debug          LICENSE          sctp         udpcliserv
DISCLAIMER     Make.defines     select       unixdomain
icmpd          Make.defines.in  server       VERSION
```

6. copy this libunp.a file inside your working dir (my working dir is one directory is in ../unpv13e, one directory up from the installation.

```
$ ls 
example.c  libunp.a  unpv13e
```

7. compile with:

```
$ gcc -o example -Iunpv13e/lib example.c libunp.a
```

8. the executable is created (the example file):

```
arbol@arbol:~/C/UnixNetworkProgramming/test
$ ls
example  example.c  libunp.a  unpv13e
arbol@arbol:~/C/UnixNetworkProgramming/test


$ ./example 127.0.0.1
bind error: Permission denied
arbol@arbol:~/C/UnixNetworkProgramming/test
$ sudo ./example 127.0.0.1
```